# CMake: File Globbing in subdirectories

Tags: cmake

I want to add an install directive (i.e.: I want to have `make install` do the right thing) to google mock and google test frameworks in CMake as I need them to be cross compiled.

Since this is an external library I want to keep changes rather non-inversive.
Is there a possibility to get CMake File Globbing working to glob a subdirectory without using `GLOB_RECURSE`?

the problem I encounter with gtest is that include/gtest/interal gets flattened by the function I defined if I glob recursively. Hence files in the directory include/gtest/internal get installed to `${prefix}/include/gtest` instead `${prefix}/include/gtest/internal`

if possible I'd like to not add `CMakeLists.txt` files in the include directories.

```
function(install_header dest_dir)
    foreach(header ${ARGN})
        install(FILES include/${header}
            DESTINATION include/google/${dest_dir}
        )
    endforeach()
endfunction()

# doesn't work with GLOB
# but works with GLOB_RECURSE -- however copies more than intended
file(GLOB headers RELATIVE ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ *.h.pump *.h )
file(GLOB internalheaders RELATIVE ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include/gtest/internal/ *.h.pump *.h )
if(NOT headers)
message(FATAL_ERROR "headers not found")
endif()
if(NOT internalheaders)
message(FATAL_ERROR "headers not found")
endif()

install_header(gtest ${headers})
install_header(gtest/internal ${internalheaders})
```

Comment: Have you considered `install(DIRECTORY ... FILES_MATCHING ...)`?

Comment: @Angew Oh dear. I must've been blind. that looks a ton less of everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer.

I believe you should be able to achieve what you intend with `install(DIRECTORY ...)`:

```
install(
  DIRECTORY ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include/  #notice trailing slash - will not append "include" to destination
  DESTINATION include/google/gtest
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h.pump" PATTERN "*.h"  # install only files matching a pattern
  PATTERN REGEX "/internal/" EXCLUDE  # ignore files matching this pattern (will be installed separately)
)

install(
  DIRECTORY ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include/gtest/internal  #notice no trailing slash - "internal" will be appended to destination
  DESTINATION include/google/gtest
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h.pump" PATTERN "*.h"  # install only files matching a pattern
)
```

I am not familiar with gtest directory structure; the above assumes the headers are in `include` and in `include/gtest/internal`. If the headers you're interested in reside in `include/gtest` and `include/gtest/internal`, you can add `gtest` to the first directory name, and get rid of the `EXCLUDE` pattern and the second `install` command.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't help me at all. as the zip file is checked in and not the source. and implementing a patcher is more expensive that installing the 10 header files somehow else ..